# What is the selector to check if an input tag has text entered or not?

Tags: jquery, input, selector

I want to grab all inputs of type=text that have nothing entered by the user. My selector so far is:

`$('input[type=text]')`

, but I don't know how, if there is a way, to also check the text of the input in the selector. I know I can check using .text(), but I want to know if there's a way to put it in the selector itself. I'm basically looking for:

```
$('input[type=text][text != ""]')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text entered by the user is available in the `value` attribute, so you can use an [Attribute Not Equal](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) selector:

```
var nonEmptyInputs = $("input[type='text'][value!='']");
```

*Note:* My original answer used the [:text](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) selector instead of an [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
var nonEmptyInputs = $("input:text[value!='']");
```

However, `:text` is both slower than the Attribute Equals selector *and* deprecated in jQuery 1.7, so the first syntax should probably be preferred.

Comment: Oh, damn. I was pretty close in my pseudo-code above. Hehe. Very cool.

Comment: I liked your original notation better. Just didn't know I could write it that way. Maybe put both in there for future users?

Comment: Okay, I'll reinstate it, but it's slower, and I just learnt it's deprecated.

Comment: Worth noting that `:text` did more than just mimic `input[type=text]`. The `type` attribute is optional and the default is `text`. `:text` would select `input` nodes with no `type` attribute, the CSS version does not. This means if you don't use `:text` there is *no way* to select all valid text inputs with jQuery.. or you have to ensure that you always have a type attribute. Personally I think it's too bad they deprecated this, it solved a problem with CSS that has now been un-solved.